# SoPlex basis file format

Tags: simplex, software, scip, mps, lp-format

I'm running SoPlex from the command line to solve some linear programming problems. I'd like to get the basis of the solution, so I use the `--writebas` flag. However, I can't find a description of the file format of the basis output.  For example, running
`soplex test.lp --writebas=basis` on

```
\ test.lp
Maximize
 obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + x4
Subject To
 c1: - x1 + x2 + x3 + 10 x4 <= 20
 c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
 c3: x2 - 3.5 x4 = 0
Bounds
 0 <= x1 <= 40
 2 <= x4 <= 3
General
 x4
End
```

gives the basis file:

```
NAME  soplex.bas
 UL x1
 XU x2             c1
 XU x3             c2
 XL x4             c3
ENDATA
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a standard MPS Basis file. Its format goes back to ancient Roman times. Here is a good description: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/bas-format.htm.

Comment: ...Ancient roman times...